# select.select is unblocked when a new connection is established

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

below is a code snippet extracted from [select pymotw-3](http://pymotw.com/3/select/index.html), kind of confused about this line: `readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)`.

When the echo server is up, the code runs and blocks at the `select.select` function, but why a new connection would make the code run again when there are no changes to `inputs` and `outputs`? any ideas?

```
# select_echo_server.py
import select
import socket
import sys
import queue

# Create a TCP/IP socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setblocking(0)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address),
      file=sys.stderr)
server.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
server.listen(5)

# Sockets from which we expect to read
inputs = [server]

# Sockets to which we expect to write
outputs = []

# Outgoing message queues (socket:Queue)
message_queues = {}

while inputs:
    # Wait for at least one of the sockets to be
    # ready for processing

    ###### THIS WOULD BLOCK ######
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs,
                                                    outputs,
                                                    inputs)
    # Handle inputs
    for s in readable:
        if s is server:
            # A "readable" socket is ready to accept a connection
            connection, client_address = s.accept()
            print('  connection from', client_address,
                  file=sys.stderr)
            connection.setblocking(0)
            inputs.append(connection)
    ...
```

Comment: Because the `server` socket is in the `inputs` list. And there *is* a change to the `inputs`. When a client connects to your socket, `select` will indicate ready-to-read on the listening socket.

Comment: @GilHamilton thanks, I thought `listen` can make the `server` on `ready-to-read` state, turns out not.